# Telegram Bot Api / Python: Trying to send voice message via my telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

so im playing a little bit around with my telegram bot, now im already able to send normal messages and pictures. But now i want to be able to send pre recorded voice messages as an answer. In the documentation it says to use send_voice for this matter and it recommends using the file_id of a file thats already on the telegram servers. So thats what i did i send a voice message to the @RawDataBot and he returned to me the file_id of the voice message.

Problem is: When i try to trigger it i get the following error: telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified

Any ideas here on what i might be doing wrong? Here is the relevant code:

```
import telebot

API_KEY = <MY_API_KEY>


bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY)





#start
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start (message):
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id,Textstart)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['pic'])
def start (photo):    
  bot.send_photo(photo.chat.id, "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeus#/media/Datei:Zeus_Otricoli_Pio-Clementino_Inv257.jpg")

#here is the part where he is supposed to send the voice message if someone types in /audio
@bot.message_handler(commands=['audio'])
def start (voice):
  bot.send_voice(voice.chat.id,"AwACAgIAAxkBAAEWjl5i5bjyudWAM9IISKWhE1Gjs5ntQgACLx8AApcNKEv97pVasPhBoCkE",)




bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple reasons, but I think it is because of these: 
**file_id** is unique for each individual bot and **can't** be transferred from one bot to another. 
**file_id** uniquely identifies a file, but a file can have different valid **file_id**s even for the same bot. 
See [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files).

Comment: ok so how do i find out the correct file_id then? or is there another way to send the voice message?

Comment: send or forward the message (here is voice) to your own bot, then if you print message object, you can see file_id.